# How to get a rows data that has the highest score for each player

Tags: mysql

For example I have the below data.

```
PlayerId, data, score
1, 0, 20
1, 1, 10
2, 0, 30
2, 1, 40
2, 0, 40
```

How do i get the below result?

```
PlayerId, data, score
1, 0 20
2, 1, 40
```

for row 2 of result it doesn't matter if it returns data 0 instead of 1 because 40 is max score for 0 and 1, returning either one is okay I just one row returned for each player with a possible data of he max(score).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT PlayerId,MAX(`data`) AS `data`, MAX(score) AS score
FROM your_table
GROUP BY PlayerId
```

**EDIT:**

The first version will  get the both `MAX` values. Now I see you want data from actual row:

```
SELECT PlayerId, score, MAX(`data`) AS `data`
FROM your_table
WHERE (PlayerId, score) IN (SELECT PlayerId, MAX(score)
                          FROM your_table
                          GROUP BY PlayerId)
GROUP BY PlayerId, score;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57086/1/0)**</kbd>

Comment: was about to answer the same thing, welp xD

Comment: what if the data had another row like 2, 0, 50? I want 2, 0, 50 returned...doesn't this return 2,1,50?

Comment: @TinTran Yes you are right. I updated my answer and added demo